# WPF Design-view crash

Tags: wpf

I use  VS2010 professional (sp1) and OS is Windows 7

I've created WPF-project and its target framework is Framework 4 - Not Framework 4 client.

That's because I need also crystal reports, which on the other hand needs following settings:

**PROBLEM** is that Design-view crashes when I try to handle page/window. 
Clicking link *"Click here to reload the designer"*
view normalize but - of course it crashes again if I do something.

Error message (part of it):

> **"System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo
>   method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig,
>   MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method,
>   Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes
>   methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture,
>   Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)    at
>   System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
>   catchHandler)
>
> System.Reflection.Adds.UnresolvedAssemblyException Type universe
>   cannot resolve assembly: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a."**

If I change Target Framework to Framework 4 client, handling of page/window works fine - except of crystal reports.

Is it possible to use crystal reports in WPF 4 project

Answer (score 0):

It tells you whats wrong. It can't load the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell v2.0 assembly. That doesn't really have anything to do with CrystalReports.